# Problem in a INNER JOIN Statement for SUM

Tags: sql

I use the following question but the sum answers are not correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
  TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.DOC_NO AS PDN, 
  DOC_NO,
  CONVERT(varchar(8), TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.DOC_DT, 112) AS DATE_1, 
  CONVERT(varchar(8), TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.ACT_RECEIPT_DATE, 112) AS DATE_2,
  SUM(TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.QTY) AS RCVQTY,
  SUM TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.ADVICED_QTY) AS ADVQTY
FROM TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD
INNER JOIN TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE ON TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.RECEIPT_HEAD_ID =
                                    TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.RECEIPT_HEAD_ID
  AND TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.X_PART_ID = (
    SELECT X_PART_ID FROM TB_X_PART WHERE PARTNO_BUYER = '146620' 
       AND CAT_COMPANY_ID = '30')
GROUP BY DOC_NO, DOC_DT,ACT_RECEIPT_DATE,ADVICED_QTY
ORDER BY DATE_2 DESC, DATE_1 DESC
```

The output gives me

```
  PDN           DOC_NO  DATE_1          DATE_2          RCVQTY  ADVQTY
1 125527    125527  20190312    20190313    50.000  50.000
2 124335    124335  20190108    20190109    4.000   4.000
3 124335    124335  20190108    20190109    50.000  50.000
```

The rows 2 and 3 should only be one row with quantity 54.000 because the values on PDN, DOC_NO, DATE_1 and DATE_2 are the same. 
Im lost.

/Stefan

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read.

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases!

Comment: `TOP 3` hints SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: I guess I believe you when you say the numbers are not correct.  There is no other information available to know what the right values are.

Comment: It seems his keyboard does not have lower case letters. Sigh.

Comment: all the non aggregated columns should be in the GROUP BY. Not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: DOC_NO, DOC_DT,ACT_RECEIPT_DATE,ADVICED_QTY must be different for those two rows you mentioned, so the GROUP BY separates them.

Comment: You are missing a ( for the SUM() for ADVQTY.  Also, the AND in your Join on should not be there.  Either put in in the WHERE after the join or use a virtual table to join to.  Plus what was said above, you are grouping by more fields that you are returning.  If DOC_NO should be your unique ID in the result only group by DOC_NO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

SELECT PDN, DOC_NO, DATE_1, DATE_2, SUM(RCVQTY), SUM(ADVQTY) 
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3
          TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.DOC_NO AS PDN, 
          DOC_NO,
          CONVERT(varchar(8), TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.DOC_DT, 112) AS DATE_1, 
          CONVERT(varchar(8), TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.ACT_RECEIPT_DATE, 112) AS DATE_2,
          SUM(TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.QTY) AS RCVQTY,
          SUM TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.ADVICED_QTY) AS ADVQTY
        FROM TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD
        INNER JOIN TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE ON TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_HEAD.RECEIPT_HEAD_ID =
                                            TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.RECEIPT_HEAD_ID
          AND TB_GOODS_RECEIPT_LINE.X_PART_ID = (
            SELECT X_PART_ID FROM TB_X_PART WHERE PARTNO_BUYER = '146620' 
               AND CAT_COMPANY_ID = '30')
        GROUP BY DOC_NO, DOC_DT,ACT_RECEIPT_DATE,ADVICED_QTY
        ORDER BY DATE_2 DESC, DATE_1 DESC ) 
GROUP BY DN, DOC_NO, DATE_1, DATE_2

Answer (score 0):

You should not be grouping by ADVICED_QTY. I think that is why you are not getting one row instead of two for the last two rows.

Comment: Thanks. I removed ADVICED_QTY from the grouping and now i works. Can´t remeber why i had it from when i wrote this.